# SQL Server : conditional WHERE-clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, conditional-operator

This is my first question so hope its all good!

What I have done is a user-defined (table valued) function using MSSMS, where in one point, I have to find records based on the functions parameter @Year.

Problem for me arises when records are older than two years, then it should list all the record which are older than two years. I have been banging my head on the wall with this one, and this is where I have gotten so far:

```
WHERE   (
        @Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) = @Year
        OR
        @Year = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) = @Year
        OR
        @Year = YEAR(GETDATE())-2 AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) = @Year
        OR
        @Year <= YEAR(GETDATE())-3 AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) < @Year
        )
```

Comment: So, what *is* the problem? Are you getting incorrect results? An error message? The feeling that it should look "cleaner"?

Comment: Oh, yeah. This code wont return anything if the year is older than two years.

Comment: Well, you have a mismatch of `<=` and `<` in your last tests - so what input `@Year` value are you giving, and do you have data that is from years *before* that one? Maybe if you could add some example data, your `@Year` input values and expected results, we could help.

Comment: Oh, I actually figured out it wasn't my code that I was struggling with but the actual data was wrong. But thank you for the quick replys Damien. Closing this question when I can..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE   (
        (@Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) = @Year)
        OR
        (@Year = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) = @Year)
        OR
        (@Year = YEAR(GETDATE())-2 AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) = @Year)
        OR
        (@Year <= YEAR(GETDATE())-3 AND YEAR(E.ExampleColumnDate) < @Year)
        )
```

Comment: What kind of answer is this ? You just repeated the where clause. No improvement nor any comments

Comment: No, that's a different clause. Look at the parentheses.

Comment: @JohnSaunders you are right, I had not seen that. There is still a problem - those parentheses makes absolutely no difference in the logic or result

Comment: I just accepted the answer to close this question because the results were fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can get records are older than two years with this also

```
;with cte 
as
(
SELECT top 10 DATEDIFF(year,E.ExampleColumnDate, getdate()) as diff, * 
  FROM [yourtablename]
  )
  select * from cte where diff =2
```